# Google Map Marker not working when from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm starting to learn Google Map. It's strange that when statically declared, markers are working and being displayed, but when they come from DB, they aren't being drawn on map.

```
// var markers = [[15.054419, 120.664785, 'Device1'], [15.048203, 120.692186, 'Device 2'], [15.033303, 120.694611, 'Device 3']];
var markers = [];
```

I have the entire code here, maybe I am missing something? I even used console log and I successfully pass all data from ajax to `markers` variable.

I think I got this code somewhere here in SO and modified it to fit in for my DB calls  for records. I hope you can help me out on this one. Thank you!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var global_markers = [];    
// var markers = [[15.054419, 120.664785, 'Device1'], [15.048203, 120.692186, 'Device 2'], [15.033303, 120.694611, 'Device 3']];
    var markers = [];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(15.058607, 120.660884);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'control_panel/get_device_list_ajax',
            success: 
                function (data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (data['success']){
                        var device = data['device_list'];
                        device.forEach(function (dev) {
                            markers.push([dev['dev_geolat'], dev['dev_geolng'], dev['dev_name']]);
                            //console.log(markers);
                        });
                        addMarker();
                    } else {

                    }
                }
        });
    }

    function addMarker() {
        console.log(markers);
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            // obtain the attribues of each marker
            var lat = parseFloat(markers[i][0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(markers[i][1]);
            var trailhead_name = markers[i][2];

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            var contentString = "<html><body><div><p><h2>" + trailhead_name + "</h2></p></div></body></html>";

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Coordinates: " + lat + " , " + lng + " | Trailhead name: " + trailhead_name
            });

            marker['infowindow'] = contentString;

            global_markers[i] = marker;

            google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }

    window.onload = initialize;
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the jsfiddle I used to work with this one http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/ZLuTg/ (thank you to the one that lead me to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be related to the way you accessing to json rendered  by ajax

```
markers.push([dev.dev_geolat, dev.dev_geolng, dev.dev_name]);
```

or the json content

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly. But it has the same effect, I still get the same `console.log(markers);` of the `device_list` but no markers on Google Map.

Comment: show a (short) sample of  your markers  json result

Comment: OMG! I'm sorry. I just found out that after some hours checking why they don't display, my DB values are incorrect due to wrong table field data type (`lat/lng`). Thank you that I checked the results on console log and overlooked them before posting a question. Thank you again for help. it's now working.

Comment: if my suggestions have been useful for you mark the answer as helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to close this question as I overlooked some problems on my DB but I'll be posting my answer if someone may come with the same problem (well, I am not sure about that hehe)

I get the same response from AJAX of the values in DB and I am not able to draw markers on MAP, I found that `db->table->fields LAT LNG` are referenced with a data type of `DECIMAL (7,5)` and changed it to `FLOAT (10, 6)` as to what is found in this [GOOGLE MAP Tutorial - Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?csw=1).

The issue at the field before was that higher values tend to be saved as 99.999999 instead of the actual value (e.g. 120.XXXXX) .